# Is there a way to call multiple URLs with XMLHttprequest?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

/* Hello peeps,

I hope you can help me, I'm trying to get 3 different tickers from the same coinmarket URL. I would like to be able to call honey coin, bitcoin and game credits  within the same script. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an option with this API to call them specifically all at once BUT there is an option to call a huge list of them and extract them that way, although it would be difficult to determine which is which (as I have no idea how to go about that).

*-if you were wondering-*:
 The Anthropodia targets are an 'in-game currency' and the first iteration of this script did work thanks to stackoverflow's own Fen1x. :) The object is to have our in-game currencies fluctuate realistically by using cryptos. Players will later be able to influence the game by buying cryptos... right now I'm just setting up the webpage, anyway I tried two different methods,

Nothing comes out of this first example, just a blank page and unfortunately I think this is way over my head. I tried to circumvent this by calling a group of tickers and just using the first 3 object 'price_usd's but that doesn't fit the original plan. So does anyone out there have an answer for either first or second examples or both?

the first try:

I will be happy to add your username or real name (if you like) into the game credits and on our webpage and anyone interested in joining our game project is more than welcome (its all voluntary and I'm the only coder with javascript knowledge, also, I pulled the short straw. :)

---

*/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <head>
    <title>Displaying JSON Data</title>
    </head>


<script type="text/javascript"> 


        window.addEventListener('load',init,false);

function init(e) {
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click',documentLoader,false);
}

function reqListener() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById('honey_price_usd').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd; //Honey Coin Price 
    document.getElementById('Anthropodia Honey Price').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd * 10; //Anthropodia Honey Price * 10 

}


function reqListener() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById('game_price_usd').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd; //Game Credits Price 
    document.getElementById('Anthropodia Sugar Price').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd * 10; //Anthropodia Sugar Price * 10 

}

function reqListener() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById('btc_price_usd').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd; //Bitcoin Price 
    document.getElementById('Anthropodia Asparatime Price').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd * 10; //Anthropodia Asparatime Price * 10 

}


function documentLoader(){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener; 
    oReq.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/HONEY/?convert=USD",true); 
    oReq.send(); 
}

function documentLoader(){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener; 
    oReq.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/gamecredits/?convert=USD",true); 
    oReq.send(); 
}

function documentLoader(){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener; 
    oReq.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=USD",true); 
    oReq.send(); 
}
</script>

<body>

<!-- Form that holds Anthropodia Currency Prices --> 

    <form id="Currency_Form" style="width:50%">
         <table style="width:100%">
<center>         <h1>Anthropodia Currency</h1>      </center> 
  <tr>
    <th>Crypto-Currency</th>
    <th>Game Currency</th>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Honey Coin Price: <div id="honey_price_usd"></div></td>
    <td>Anthropodia Honey Price: <div id="Anthropodia Honey Price"></div></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Game Credits Price: <div id="game_price_usd"></div></td>
    <td>Anthropodia Sugar Price: <div id="Anthropodia Sugar Price"></div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Bitcoin Price: <div id="btc_price_usd"></div></td>
    <td>Anthropodia Asparatime Price: <div id="Anthropodia Asparatime Price"></div></td>
  </tr>

</table>

    <center> 

    <button id="myButton" type="button">Click to load</button>

    <center>  

</form> 



</body> 

</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <head>
    <title>Displaying JSON Data</title>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.addEventListener('load',init,false);

function init(e) {
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click',documentLoader,false);
}

function reqListener() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById('honey_price_usd').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd; //Honey Coin Price 
    document.getElementById('Anthropodia Honey Price').innerHTML= obj[0].price_usd * 10; //Honey Coin Price * 10 
    document.getElementById('game_price_usd').innerHTML= obj[1].price_usd; //Game Credit Price
    document.getElementById('Anthropodia Sugar Price').innerHTML= obj[1].price_usd * 10; //Sugar Coin Price * 10 
    document.getElementById('btc_price_usd').innerHTML= obj[2].price_usd; //Bitcoin Price 
    document.getElementById('Anthropodia Asparatime Price').innerHTML= obj[2].price_usd * 10; //Asparatime Coin Price * 10 

}

function documentLoader(){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener; 
    oReq.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10",true); 
    oReq.send(); 
}

/* Thanks go out to Fen1x from Stackoverflow for helping fix the code (you are also on the webpage) */ 
        </script>

    </head>
<body>

<!-- Form that holds Anthropodia Currency Prices --> 

    <form id="Currency_Form" style="width:50%">
         <table style="width:100%">
<center>         <h1>Anthropodia Currency</h1>      </center> 
  <tr>
    <th>Crypto-Currency</th>
    <th>Game Currency</th>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Honey Coin Price: <div id="honey_price_usd"></div></td>
    <td>Anthropodia Honey Price: <div id="Anthropodia Honey Price"></div></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Game Credits Price: <div id="game_price_usd"></div></td>
    <td>Anthropodia Sugar Price: <div id="Anthropodia Sugar Price"></div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Bitcoin Price: <div id="btc_price_usd"></div></td>
    <td>Anthropodia Asparatime Price: <div id="Anthropodia Asparatime Price"></div></td>
  </tr>

</table>

    <center> 

    <button id="myButton" type="button">Click to load</button>

    <center>  

</form> 



</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: No takers eh... well if I figure this out on my own, Ill be sure and post it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call that huge file, better do 3 ajax calls.

As for your functions, those same function names overwrite each other so only the last one will work, like with `var x=1,x=2,x=3` then x will be 3. So you need 3 different function names, or use 1 and pass the url and id's into it and use that inside. But I'll keep it readable for you and use 3.

Also, id's should not have spaces in them, so I replaced those with `_`, and `center` tag is not supported in html5, so I removed them.

Last be informed this code doesn't have any error handling.

```js
    

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init(e) {
  document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', documentLoader, false);
}

function reqListenerHoney() {
  var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  document.getElementById('honey_price_usd').innerHTML = obj[0].price_usd; //Honey Coin Price 
  document.getElementById('Anthropodia_Honey_Price').innerHTML = obj[0].price_usd * 10; //Anthropodia Honey Price * 10 

}

function reqListenerGame() {
  var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  document.getElementById('game_price_usd').innerHTML = obj[0].price_usd; //Game Credits Price 
  document.getElementById('Anthropodia_Sugar_Price').innerHTML = obj[0].price_usd * 10; //Anthropodia Sugar Price * 10 
}

function reqListenerBitcoin() {
  var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  document.getElementById('btc_price_usd').innerHTML = obj[0].price_usd; //Bitcoin Price 
  document.getElementById('Anthropodia_Asparatime_Price').innerHTML = obj[0].price_usd * 10; //Anthropodia Asparatime Price * 10 
}

function documentLoaderHoney() {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.onload = reqListenerHoney;
  oReq.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/HONEY/?convert=USD", true);
  oReq.send();
}

function documentLoaderGame() {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.onload = reqListenerGame;
  oReq.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/gamecredits/?convert=USD", true);
  oReq.send();
}

function documentLoaderBitcoin() {
console.log("docloader");
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.onload = reqListenerBitcoin;
  oReq.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=USD", true);
  oReq.send();
}

function documentLoader() {
   // clicked button, call the 3 functions
   documentLoaderHoney();
   documentLoaderGame();
   documentLoaderBitcoin();
}
```

```html
<form id="Currency_Form" style="width:50%">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <h1>Anthropodia Currency</h1>
    <tr>
      <th>Crypto-Currency</th>
      <th>Game Currency</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Honey Coin Price:
        <div id="honey_price_usd"></div>
      </td>
      <td>Anthropodia Honey Price:
        <div id="Anthropodia_Honey_Price"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Game Credits Price:
        <div id="game_price_usd"></div>
      </td>
      <td>Anthropodia Sugar Price:
        <div id="Anthropodia_Sugar_Price"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bitcoin Price:
        <div id="btc_price_usd"></div>
      </td>
      <td>Anthropodia Asparatime Price:
        <div id="Anthropodia_Asparatime_Price"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>


    <button id="myButton" type="button">Click to load</button>

</form>
```

Comment: You 're welcome. Have a look at the sample code in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) which combines documentLoader... and reqListener.... function and adds a check (the readystate and status line).

Comment: It works perfectly. You have a credit in our upcoming game and on the webpage. I'll post it to you shortly.